# Cannot start a Go application exe as a windows services

Tags: windows, go, windows-services

I have a application with Go language as the backend.
I can create a service using the sc and nssm as below :
`sc create TestService binpath=C:\User\sds\Desktop\test.exe nssm install TestService C:\User\sds\Desktop\test.exe`

The services are created successfully but it doesn not get started. It gives **startup timeout error** while starting the service.

I need to start the application from windows services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to the @GKV's answer: you have to understand that a Windows service is a complicated beast which is supposed to be called in a special way and do a lot of processing once started (and moreover, any executable tihing--be it an EXE or DLL--might host any number of Windows services, and many OS-provided services are run like that.)

Comment: A low-tech solution would be wrapping your application via `srvany` or `nssm` (google them, if you wish) -- which basically turn a normal (regular) Windows application into a Windows service. I'd still follow the @GKV's advice.

Comment: @kostix I have already tried using nssm but the result is same. I get the same 1053 error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go has a library for creating services in windows.
Please check this library [github.com/kardianos/service](http://github.com/kardianos/service).

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/kardianos/service"
)

var logger service.Logger

type program struct{}

func (p *program) Start(s service.Service) error {
    // Start should not block. Do the actual work async.
    go p.run()
    return nil
}
func (p *program) run() {
    // Do work here
}
func (p *program) Stop(s service.Service) error {
    // Stop should not block. Return with a few seconds.
    return nil
}

func main() {
    svcConfig := &service.Config{
        Name:        "GoServiceExampleSimple",
        DisplayName: "Go Service Example",
        Description: "This is an example Go service.",
    }

    prg := &program{}
    s, err := service.New(prg, svcConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    logger, err = s.Logger(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = s.Run()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I have read about the package [kardianos/service](https://github.com/kardianos/service)" and a similar package too "[svc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc)". But my doubt is that "What will be the code flow, since i need to bundle the exe in my installer?? Do i need to start the exe and then create a service for the same exe??".

Comment: you should keep the above code(in your main.go),when you install the .exe,using installer it will automatically start your service .