# Windows Service not start in Golang

Tags: windows, go, service

I run my go executable file as a service, and when it runs, it shows:

```
Failed to start CService: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

In **Event Viewr** it shows:

```
A timeout was reached (1572864 milliseconds) while waiting for the CService service to connect.
```

Here is what I tried to fix:

1. Set the registry key **ServicesPipeTimeout** in **Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control** to 180000 to prevent timeout
2. Run the command **sfc /scannow** to check any corrupt system files, but it is clean (no corrupt files).

Can anyone help me in this problem?

Comment: Please provide more information (it's difficult to tell you why a service did not start when you have not provided any information about the service). You indicate it's written in Go - please share some of your code (see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Do you know that you can't simply use an executable file as a service? I have no details for GO but this information might help to understand: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lpservice_main_functiona

Comment: If the above is the issue then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35607787/11810946) may help.